# Can I use App inventor with the Photon 4g?

Tags: android, motorola

I am considering switching to the Motorola Photon 4g and would like to continue to develope. I will admit myself as quite inexperienced and I currently can only use App Inventor. Is it possible to develope applications on App inventor and have it be connected to the Photon?
On another, even noobier note, are there any restrictions against developing using the Photon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App inventor will use any device that is connected to adb.  As long as you find and install the drivers, on Windows, then their should not be any problem.

On a side note you can use the emulator with App Inventor.  How to [here](http://appinventor.googlelabs.com/learn/reference/other/emulator.html).

FYI - the problem you will run into is when Google discontinues support for App Inventor.  Google has announced they are closing the Labs down and AI is part of that. Read that [here](http://appinventorblog.com/2011/08/09/app-inventor-discontinued-the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly/).

I would suggest learning some Java and start porting one of your AI apps in the Eclipse IDE.  If you are making working apps in AI then you have a basic knowledge of some of the methods used in Android all ready.  You just need to learn the Java syntax and some basic principles.  I reccomend working your way through this free class [here](http://math.hws.edu/javanotes/).

With Google and StackOverflow you should progress well.

Comment: Thank you, that was incredibly helpful. I will try that class. The problem that I have run into is syntax. I guess it is just practice though.